# Merge load-grunt-config data options

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to setup my Gruntfile.js to merge in specific data variables from a file that is different in each of our environments.

We are currently using the `load-grunt-config` extension like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    init: true,
    data: { //data passed into config.  Can use with <%= test %>
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      var1: 'var1',
      var2: 'var2',
      var3: 'var3',
    }
  });

  ...
```

But I'd like to do something like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    init: true,
    data: jQuery.extend(
      grunt.file.readJSON('grunt-data.json'),
      grunt.file.readJSON('grunt-data-environment.json'),
    )
  });

  ...
```

And set up my data files as:

```
 //grunt-data.json
 {
   pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
   var1: 'var1',
   var2: 'var2',
   var3: 'var3',
 }
```

..

```
 //grunt-data-environment.json ON DEV
 {
   var3: 'var3-dev',
 }
```

..

```
 //grunt-data-environment.json ON PROD
 {
   var1: 'var1-prod',
 }
```

Thus when using `<%= varX %>` in my tasks the appropriate variable override will be used.

Unfortunately I can't use `jQuery` here, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `grunt-stage` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-stage - full disclosure: I am the author of the plugin).

You define 2 files: `prod.json` and `dev.json`. Then call `<%= stg.varX %>` in your config, and you get the value of the file corresponding to the stage you specified - for example by calling `grunt stage:dev:build`.